# In pentaho Data Integration, update field value in a row, depending on field values of other input rows

Tags: pentaho

I have created one transformation in which rows are generated after several step. Now as a next step, I want to calculate field value for each row based on values of other rows (it is custom logic, so necessary to have access at all rows at one shot).

I considered to use javascript step. In this step, I can access field values of current row but how to access values for other rows.
Same way, I checked with User Defined Java Class step, but stuck at the step where how to access  other rows value apart from current one.

Comment: Will the `Analytical Query` step work for you? It allows you to pull in values from other rows, but only for a fixed lead/lag number.

Comment: Ya I am aware about analytical query step, but frankly speaking, it is almost impossible to write complex logic with that. e.g. you want to take average of all the previous records except those records which are located in multiple of 5. or even more complex then that. Better way would be, if javascript step or UDJC step allows to access it.

Comment: So, I wonder, what solution did you go for in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Use Group by step to calculated rows. It has a lot of options such as SUM, Average, Max, Min, First non-null value, Cumulative sum (all rows option only!) , Cumulative average (all rows option only!), etc